# AngularJS alternative to timezone-picker

Tags: library, javascript, angularjs

[This is a fantastic timezone picker](https://github.com/kevalbhatt/timezone-picker), but it's designed for jQuery and we're using AngularJS. I can work around it a bit, but it's a tad awkward for what we're doing. Something built native to AngularJS would be better. I've found [angular-timezone-selector](https://github.com/mishguruorg/angular-timezone-selector) which would be great, but there's no map.

Is there any other similar library for AngularJS that has a map? In particular I'm looking for:

- A (reasonably) exhaustive list of timezones (the example one uses moment.js and moment-timezone to get this list)
- A map that shows the selected timezone, and it would be nice if the user could click on the map.
- Nice to have, but not necessary, is a quick list. The example one has buttons that appear, but if you can specify several zones to appear at the top of the list that would *also* be acceptable.

Comment: I don’t know if any, but I do think it would be helpful to specify which version of angular. Otherwise steal the map, add bindings, do the moment js calls yourself.

Comment: I was under the impression that "angularjs" meant Angular < 2 and "angular" meant 2+

Comment: I assumed you might be on 1 but couldn’t be sure. Most folks familiar with this distinction would prefer to write their own time zone picker over plug-ins/widgets.